# calculating differences in working hours in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Desc:**
I have: (in table)

- 2 columns with data to enter:

  a) start,

  b) end. (info: end must be larger than start for it to work properly)
- 2 columns with data that are calculated / are constant:

  a) actual (end-start),

  b) normative (const)
- 2 columns with data that I am trying to calculate:

  a) surplus,

  b) deficiency

**Code Action:**  (now it is working)

- the user enters the fields:

  a) start

  b) end (must be greater than start) [skip]
- field is calculated

  a) actual = end - start.
- field is conts.

  a) normative

**What I trying to achieve:**

- complete the fields:

  a) surplus  (how? => surplus = actual-normative) (if actual > normative)

  b) deficiency  (how? => deficiency = normative-actual)  (if actual < normative)

**What did I try ?:**

```js
function diff (start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end, actual, normative, surplus, deficiency] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual,.normative,.surplus,.deficiency')]
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value)
    actual.value = value
   
  }
})
// I tried:
/*    <-----------------------------comment
  if (actual.value > normative.value)
  {
  const value_an = diff_act_nor()
  surplus.value = value_an
  }
  else if (actual.value < normative.value)
  {
  const value_na = diff_nor_act()
  deficiency.value = value_na
  }
  else{
  // do nothing
  }
 }
 
 function diff_nor_act (actual, normative) {
  actual = actual.split(":");
  normative = normative.split(":");
  const actualDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, actual[0], actual[1], 0);
  const normativeDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, normative[0], normative[1], 0);
  let diff = normativeDate.getTime() - actualDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
 
 
 function diff_act_nor (actual, normative) {
  actual = actual.split(":");
  normative = normative.split(":");
  const actualDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, actual[0], actual[1], 0);
  const normativeDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, normative[0], normative[1], 0);
  let diff =  actualDate.getTime() - normativeDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    ---comment------------->  */
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>start</th>
<th>end</th>
<th>actual</th>
<th>normative</th>
<th>surplus</th>
<th>deficiency</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="day">
  <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="actual"  id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr class="day">
  <td><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
</tr>
</tbody>


</table>
```

**commented code**

a) The commented code doesn't work.

b) After uncommenting, it destroys the work code, which now works correctly

**Notes:**

a) the given "values" are random, entered to better illustrate the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
function diffMs(start, end) {
  return +start.split(":").join('') - +end.split(":").join('');
}
```

this function can help you calculate a difference for a logical purposes

I updated a demo:

```js
function diff(start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours <= 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes <= 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}

function diffMs(start, end) { // this function can help you calculate a difference for a logical purposes
  return +start.split(":").join('') - +end.split(":").join('');
}
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end, actual, normative, surplus, deficiency] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual,.normative,.surplus,.deficiency')]
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value);
    actual.value = value
    if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) >= 0) {
      surplus.value = diff(normative.value, actual.value);
    }
    if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) <= 0) {
      deficiency.value = diff(actual.value, normative.value);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>start</th>
      <th>end</th>
      <th>actual</th>
      <th>normative</th>
      <th>surplus</th>
      <th>deficiency</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```